# Where can I find the Jenkins plugin folder?

Tags: jenkins

I have a configuration where there is one master node and one slave node running Jenkins. The build jobs run on the slave.

1. Where are the plugins stored? Is it on the master or slave? If on master, what is the location?
2. Is it possible to access (copy) selected plugins to another server? Are there plugin dependencies that need to be respected?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For 1., see [Administering Jenkins, JENKINS_HOME directory](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins):

```
 JENKINS_HOME
  +- ...
  +- plugins
  +- ...
```

Re 2.: I never tried that, but copying plugins to another server including the necessary dependencies should work if you restart the other Jenkins afterwards. Hopefully the *Required Core Dependencies* section of the [respective plugin page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin) is up to date. I'd not recommend doing this in favour of Jenkins' built-in plugin management.

Comment: The issue is I am unable to download plugins into my server because of restrictions. So, I do not see any other way out rather than copying plugins.

Comment: @Aditya Really? You do have access to your server's file system (which is the more "dangerous") but you don't have access to Jenkin's plugin management?

Comment: Its a limitation that I have. The server is behind some sort of firewall I guess and so it not possible to have Jenkins plugin manager downloading stuff. The reason behind the protection of server is understandable. And hence more responsibility lies on the person handling the file system which is also quite correct in my view. Thats the trade off you make. And just another point, its not just Jenkins on the server. there are a few more applications.

Comment: For reference: See also [Jenkins can't download plugins - what URL(s) to open up on firewall?](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Jenkins-can-t-download-plugins-what-URL-s-to-open-up-on-firewall-td3753862.html).

Comment: Are you sure you're not behind a proxy server? Try asking your system admin and go to http://$JENKINS_MASTER:PORT/pluginManager/advanced - add your proxy settings and see if you can see the plugin repository

Comment: I am sure, but I'm also sure that this doesn't address me but @Aditya. ;)

Comment: JENKINS_HOME -> "By default, this is set to ~/.jenkins" . So your plugins are in ~/.jenkins/plugins for Linux

Answer (score 2):

1. Plugins are stored on master. If I remember correctly, there's a folder for plugins in the installation directory.
2. Yes, you can copy them to another server, I know that I did that almost 2 years ago. With new version of Jenkins, I'm not really sure.

Comment: How did you take care of dependencies when copying the plugins? To be more clear, I want to copy the Log Parser plugin, where can i see the dependencies?

Comment: @Aditya See the [Log Parser Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin) page: _Required Core Dependencies_.

Comment: > "With new version of Jenkins, I'm not really sure."


I can confirm this still works, had to manually rollback a plugin to an older version because jenkins crashed after an update. My version was 2.332.X