# Jenkins Wildfly deploy

Tags: jenkins, deployment, jboss, wildfly

I want to deploy a war file to wildfly from jenkins. I tried many methods but it doesn't work for me

- I used Deploy WAR/EAR to wildfly plugin but it is not working for me , i got the error :

> (FATAL: Unable to initialize command context. Build step 'Deploy
>   WAR/EAR to WildFly' marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE),

I searched for that issue and the given answers didn't help me.

- In the post build actions I used Deploy WAR/EAR to a container , it doesn't work for me too, I got the error:

> ```
>  ERROR: Build step failed with exception
>         org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to deploy to [http://hostname:9990/jmx-console/HtmlAdaptor]
>           at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.internal.JdkHttpURLConnection.connect(JdkHttpURLConnection.java:76)
>           at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss4xRemoteDeployer.invokeURL(JBoss4xRemoteDeployer.java:312)
>           at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss4xRemoteDeployer.invokeRemotely(JBoss4xRemoteDeployer.java:233)
>           at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss4xRemoteDeployer.redeploy(JBoss4xRemoteDeployer.java:194)
>           at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
>           at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:147)
>           at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:117)
>           at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:997)
>           at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:975)
>           at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:114)
>           at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeploy(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:93)
>           at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:64)
>           at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
>           at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
>           at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
>           at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
>           at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
>           at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1749)
>           at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
>           at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
>           at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
>         Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://hostname:9990/jmx-console/HtmlAdaptor
> ```

?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the WildFly management interface to listen on the network address represented by `hostname`. Otherwise it defaults to just listening on `localhost`.

The easiest way to accomplish this would be to start WildFly with an additional command line option. For example, if hostname has an IP address of 192.168.12.100, then:

```
 [wildfly-10.1.0.Final]$ bin/standalone.sh -bmanagement=192.168.12.100
```

Answer (score 0):

you trying

1. Copy dependency wildfly-cli-8.2.1.Final.jar to /WEB-INF/lib.
2. Copy dependency log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar to /WEB-INF/lib. (Not required if using Jenkins version 1.622 or later.)

[wildfly-deployer-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/wildfly-deployer-plugin)

Comment: hi, how to do so? I mean where I can find the /WEB-INF/lib directory?

Comment: You can see that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37563030/where-can-i-find-the-jenkins-plugin-folder).