# Update jenkins war on one machine and then move it to another one: possible?

Tags: jenkins

I have a machine with blocked outgoing connections so it is not possible to update jenkins nor install the plugins I need for my work.

My idea is the following: I download the jenkins .war on my personal laptop and complete the installation + the plugin download.
Then I just move this .war to the machine where I need jenkins to be up and running.

Is it possible? Where are the plugins/updated data stored? 
Also, would it be a problem the fact that my laptop has windows as os, while the destination machine is a linux RHEL?

Comment: Do you have shell access to your jenkins machine?

Comment: yes I have, I even have root privileges.

Comment: One more question. How are you trying to install jenkins plugin?

Comment: I would do that via web interface on my machine...dunno if downloaded files will be fine on linux as well though

Comment: Hi, War file you download in your local system doesn't contain any extra plugins which you install. All the extra plugins will be available in the ".jenkins" folder in C:/users/Username . For more information please check this link.[Jenkins Plugin local folder path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37563030/where-can-i-find-the-jenkins-plugin-folder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution sounds crazy :D

This could be help you:

## Update Jenkins war

If you have shell access with root privilege, there is a manual way.

- Download latest war file inside your linux, using wget , curl or just upload it using winscp from your windows.
- Stop jenkins
- Backup **EVERYTHING**: linux snapshot, jenkins workspace, jenkins war file, etc
- Replace the old war with new war
- Start jenkins

Detailed steps in this webs:

https://mohitgoyal.co/2017/02/15/upgrade-jenkins-server-to-a-new-version/

https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2016/06/upgrade-jenkins-and-plugins/

---

## Plugin

Jenkins has an option to install plugins called **Manage Plugins**

[image]

This offer two options :

- (1) Install plugins using **available** option

  For official and compatible plugins, suggested by Jenkins :

  [image]
- (2) Install plugins using upload option

  For custom plugins or when is not available on official repositories:

  [image]